# React onClick not firing when using react/addons

Tags: reactjs

I decided I needed React Addons however upon requiring this instead of just react my click events stopped getting triggered. The following example works when doing a require('react').

```
window.React = require('react/addons');
```

And

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var AppActions = require('../../actions/app-actions.js');

module.exports = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            rememberMe: false
        }
    },
    _rememberMeChanged: function(e) {
        this.setState({
            rememberMe: !this.state.rememberMe
        });
    },
    login: function() {
        AppActions.login(this.state.rememberMe);
        return true;
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <header className="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top bs-docs-nav" id="top" role="banner">
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <div className="navbar-header">
                        <button className="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
                            <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a href="../" className="navbar-brand">{ Constants.TITLE }</a>
                    </div>
                    <nav className="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse">
                        <div className="navbar-form navbar-right">
                            <div className="input-group">
                                <div className="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input checked={this.state.rememberMe} onChange={ this._rememberMeChanged } type="checkbox"/>
                                        Keep me logged in
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button disabled={ this.props.loading } onClick={ this.login }  className="btn btn-default">
                                { this.props.loading ? 'Logging In' : 'Login' }
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </header>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: any errors in the console ?

Comment: My only guess so far is that one of the react addons is stopping propagation

Comment: are you sure `window.React = require('react/addons'); ` will work? Aren't you replacing React ? (Just a guess)

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, react/addons just uses react-with-addons.js rather than standalone. Plus my components are rendered fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was being a moron. My gulp process skips some of my vendor files(including react), cleaning this solved my issues.